# Como Abrir um modal JQUERY depois de uma condição

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, pdo

Fala galera, tudo beleza? Estou começando na carreira de back-end e gostaria que me ajudassem a resolver uma dúvida em Jquery.

Aqui é um resumo do que quero fazer:

```
function modal(){
    //Modal funcionando normalmente
   };
window.setTimeout('modal()', 2000);
```

O que quero fazer é o seguinte, quero abrir este modal de mudança de senha, se encontrar o usuário no banco de dados. Então estou retornando uma classe quando encontra, e não retorno nada quando não encontra.

```js
if($(".true").length > 0){
   function modal(){
      //Modal funcionando normalmente
    }; window.setTimeout('modal()', 2000);
}
```

Mas o if não está funcionando.

No PHP está assim:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];

try{
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email=:email");
    $parametros = array('email' => $email);
    $query->execute($parametros);

    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        $row = $query->fetch();
        $nome=$row['nome'];
        $first_name=explode(' ',$nome);
        $usuario=$first_name['0'];
        if($row['bloqueio'] !='on'){
                echo '<p class="true" style="color: lime">Usuário encontrado!</p>';
            }else{
                echo '<p style="color: red">Usuário bloqueado!</p>';
            };
        
    }else{
        echo '<p style="color: red">Usuário não encontrado!</p>';
        return false;
    }

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    $erros.='Erro ao consultar usuário ' . $e->getMessage();
}   
  }else{ 
      echo '';
   };
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tente trocar isso:

```js
if($(".true").length > 0){
   function modal(){
      //Modal funcionando normalmente
    }; window.setTimeout('modal()', 2000);
}
```

Por isso:

```js
if($(".true")){
   function modal(){
      //Modal funcionando normalmente
    }; window.setTimeout('modal()', 2000);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Natan! Deu certo aqui.

Comment: Magina irmão, já sofri muito com modal, sei bem como é hahaha